# Why is comproportionation thermodynamically favoured for the synthesis of Mn(acac)3?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, redox

I'm currently learning about ligands in school and I'm wondering why does comproportionation happen in the overall equation? There are fewer chemical species on the product side and the entropy of the reaction would decrease. Since entropy decreases, delta G would be more positive and the reaction would not be thermodynamically favoured. Is my reasoning correct?

$$\ce{4 Mn^2+ + 8 CH3COCH2COCH3 ->  4  Mn(CH3COCHCOCH3)2 + 8 H+}$$

$\ce{Mn^{II}}$ intermediate reacts with $\ce{MnO4-}$ to form stable $\ce{Mn^{III}(acac)3}$.
$$\ce{ MnO4^- + 7 CH3COCH2COCH3 + 4  Mn(CH3COCHCOCH3)2 + H+ -> \\  -> 5  Mn(CH3COCHCOCH3)3 + 4 H2O}$$

Overall equation:
$$\ce{ 4 Mn^2+ + MnO4^- + 15 CH3COCH2COCH3 ->  5  Mn(CH3COCHCOCH3)3 + 4 H2O + 7H+}$$

Comment: Umm, how could Mn(II) **not** react with MnO4-?

Comment: I understand that the reaction can proceed but I'm not really sure how to put it in terms of the thermodynamics behind the reaction.

Comment: Mn(II) in acidic environment does react with MnO4-. But SRP Mn III/II is almost identical to Mn VII/II. acac just shifts the equilibrium.

Answer (score 1):

Disproportionation and comproportionation are not special cases to be treated differently than other redox reactions. They just happen to have some element in 3 different oxidation states. The thermodynamics remain the same as if it were not the case.

I assume the standard redox potential $E^°(\ce{Mn^{III}(acac)3/Mn^{II}(acac)2})$ is lower then $E^°(\ce{[Mn^{III}(H2O)6]^3+/[Mn^{II}(H2O)6]^2+})$, because  $\ce{Mn^{III}}$ forms more stable complex with acac and therefore Mn^{II} is more easily oxidized.

It is situation analogical to $\ce{Co^{III}/Co^{II}}$, where  $\ce{[Co^{III}(H2O)6]^3+}$ is very strong oxidant, but $\ce{[Co^{II}(NH3)6]^2+}$ is easily  oxidized by aerial oxygen.

It follows the general scheme that more stable complex with oxidized metal form leads to greater ox/red metal complex ratio than ox/red metal ratio. That means, as both ratios has to lead to the same redox potential, the complex pair has to have lover *standard* redox potential. And vice versa for more stable complex with reduced  metal form.

Comment: ahh I see. Can I also explain that comproportionation is stable due to chelation effect? Manganese would initally form a complex with water and then H2O ligands get replaced by acac to form a more stable complex?